# GNU screen quitting -- sigterm to running process

Tags: gnu-screen, signal

I want to `quit` screen session. For this, I use `screen -S session_name -X quit`.
This works well, but not like I would.

The program running in `screen` has a handler for `SIGTERM`, and I really need this handler to execute, so that it can perform proper cleanup. However, running `screen -S session_name -X quit` results in the program quitting without having its handler invoked.

A simple `kill $(pidof bla)`  results in the invocation of my handler, proper cleaning, and finally the closing of the `screen` session.

However, I'd like to be able to stop all this by closing the `screen` using its session's name, and letting it "forward" the `SIGTERM` signal.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't see any other way than a script that read the tree of process spawned from the original screen (session should match PID) and send SIGTERM to all process starting with leaves. At the end of the script, just send the screen quit command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came with is inspired by the one suggested by @Kwaio.
I my case, I only have one process that is interested in receiving the `SIGTERM` signal. This process already forward it to its children.

This assumes that there is only one `screen` session with a given name.

```
kill $(ps h --ppid $(screen -ls | grep session_name | cut -d. -f1) -o pid)
```